# JVectorMap and Respond.js Crash on IE8

Tags: jvectormap, respond.js

I try to include JVectorMap plugin: http://jvectormap.com.

But i need also to include respond.js for my project: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.

My problem is when i include jvectormap only in IE8, it works,
but when i also include respond.min.js, it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>     
<![endif]-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
```